# php app sessions are confused when working with two chrome browsers

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, session, cookies

I have a php application with MySQL database. users and their passwords are stored in the database. the problem is that, sometimes, several users work on the same computer simultaneously, each with its session. When we used the system with internet explorer, it worked well, but now started using google chrome.
what happens is that the sessions are confused, suddenly, the user "x", performs some operation, and the session becomes the session user "Y".
 I wish you could help me, because I do not want to return to Internet Explorer. Thank you.

Here I leave the code as open the session:

```
$cons = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$textLogin' AND password = '$pwd'";
$result = mysql_query($cons, $conexion);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    /*
    session_name(encriptar($textLogin));
    session_start(encriptar($textLogin));
    */
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    $nroId = session_id();

    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_id($nroId);
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
    { 
    session_start(); 
    }  

/*  session_register($nroId);*/

    $_SESSION["loginUsr"] = $row["login"];
    $_SESSION["passwordUsr"] = $pwd;
    $_SESSION["idUser"] = $row["idUser"];
    $_SESSION["name"] = $row["name"];
    $_SESSION["lastname"] = $row["lastname"];


}
```

And this code is executed every time a php page is called (The session_id is sent every time in the url as "login") :

```
$sigueCheckS = 0;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    if (isset($_GET["login"])) {
        $textLogin = $_GET["login"];
        $sigueCheckS = 1;
    } else {
        $sigueCheckS = 0;
        $textLogin = "";
    };
};
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    //if (!empty($_REQUEST["login"])) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST["login"])) {
        $sigueCheckS = 1;
        $textLogin = $_REQUEST["login"];
    } else {
        $sigueCheckS = 0;
        $textLogin = "";
    };
};

if ($sigueCheckS == 1) {
    session_id($textLogin);
    /*COMENTAR ESTAS TRES LINEAS*/
    $horas = 4;
    $tiempo = $horas * 3600;
    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",$tiempo);
    /*COMENTAR ESTAS TRES LINEAS*/
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
     if (!isset($_SESSION["idUsuarioUsr"])) { 
        //echo "<br>no registrado";
        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php?errorLogin=4';</script>";
        return; 
    };
} else {
    //echo "<br>todo bien";
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='index.php?errorLogin=4';</script>";
    return;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Canary:**

If your computers are running Windows or OSX you can use [Google Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html). Just install the plugin and click the sessions cookie icon at the end of the address bar. It will open a new window with it's own session data.

Comment: Hello, i installed Google Chrome Canary but didn't found the cookie icon.